# Delphi 10 Seattle Launcher app (FMX)

Tags: android, delphi, android-manifest, delphi-10-seattle

I have developed an application in Delphi XE6 that acts as a launcher for mimicking kiosk mode by adding some informations to the android manifest. It works well. After migrating all my projects to Delphi 10 Seattle I discovered that this application just wouldnt be acceppted as a launcher app any more. The packaged manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.embarcadero.psmBus"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.0"
        android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_BACK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="False" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
        android:label="psmBus" 
        android:debuggable="True" 
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">



        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="psmBus"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="psmBus" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" />

    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

Is anyone aware of changes in this area from XE8 to 10 Seattle?

Comment: `wouldnt be acceppted as a launcher app` - does the application appear in the Android application launcher?

Comment: Yes it does. But with XE6 this compiled and on pressing the home button it was offered as alternative launcher whicht I use to mimic kiosk mode.

Comment: In earlier versions (prior to D10), the receiver line read `<receiver android:name=”com.embarcadero.firemonkey.notifications.FMXNotificationAlarm” />`, though I'm not really sure what the implications are, or why they changed it.